# firebug: is it possible to save output to file?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have a test engineer to reproduce bugs for me, the bug is random so I want him to save the log to the file when it occurs, is it possible?

Comment: I'm interested to know if there's a way to do this, though I don't think that there is at present.

Comment: The only way I know of is copy-paste, but I'll be watching this question right along with Pointy in case there is a better way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/) which is a FireBug extension that allows you to save the collected/computed data from the Net panel.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but that feature has not been implimented in firebug. (http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=193)

There is an addon export from the NetExport. you might want to check that out: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/